# How to configure 2 api laravel 5.6 and a "normal" in debian

Tags: laravel, api, routes, apache2

I have a Debian server 9 with Apache 2 and Laravel 5.6

I have the folder: `/LcmTI/projects/www` to publish my projects, port 81 answers for all projects, eg:
`http://localhost: 81/project1` [html project only]

In the folder `/LcmTI/projects/laravel`, I have two laravel projects 5.6:

- extranet at `/LcmTI/projects/laravel/extranet`
- intranet at `/LcmTI/projects/laravel/intranet`

I have created a link to the two projects in the `www` folder (which is the folder that is published):

- `ln -s /LcmTI/projects/laravel/extranet/public /LcmTI/projects/www/extranet`
- `ln -s /LcmTI/projects/laravel/intranet/public /LcmTI/projects/www/intranet`

In this way, I expected without any problem to access the two laravel environments without any problem, but it is not working.

When I type:
`http://localhost:81/extranet/api/test` or `http://localhost:81/intranet/api/test`
does not work and should return:

```
/* file routes/api.php in both applications */

`Route::get('test', function () {
    return response()-> json(['foo' => 'bar']);
});`
```

If I enter `http://localhost:81/extranet` or `http://localhost:81/intranet`
Enter the homepage of Laravel

My configuration for Apache 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>

DocumentRoot /LcmTI/projects/www

<Directory /LcmTI/projects/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm having a hard time setting up larval API applications on a single host.